# Flutter widget second row consume remaining space

Tags: flutter, widget

I am fairly new to flutter, many things I don't understand yet.  I have tried many things and I can't get what I want yet.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        // make the full container the amber color
        color: Colors.amber[600],
        child: Column(children: [
          Row(children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                windowName,
                style: TextStyle(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[200],
                    fontSize: 24,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: onCurrentDelete,
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete_outline, size: 32)),
          ]),
          //IntrinsicHeight(
          //  child:
          Row(
            //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  // make the left container blue
                  color: Colors.blue[600],
                  //constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
                  //decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  //    border: Border.all(
                  //  width: 2,
                  //)),
                  child: Text(
                    startTime,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[200],
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                  )),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  // make the right container green
                  color: Colors.green[600],
                  //decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  //    border: Border.all(
                  //  width: 2,
                  //)),
                  child: Text(
                    endTime,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[200],
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                  )),
              )
            ],
          ),
          //),
        ]),
      ),
    )
  ]);
```

What I want is the two containers in the last row to take up the remaining space.  I have used color attribute to show the size of specific widgets.

[image: Text]

The blue and green containers need to fill the to the bottom of the amber section.

[image]

I have tried many alternatives and each time the widget generates a fault when it is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

**Image**
[image]

**Code:**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              // make the full container the amber color
              color: Colors.amber[600],
              child: Column(children: [
                Row(children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      "windowName",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[200],
                          fontSize: 24,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: Icon(Icons.delete_outline, size: 32)),
                ]),
                //IntrinsicHeight(
                //  child:
                Row(
                  //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        // make the left container blue
                        color: Colors.blue[600],
                        //constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
                        //decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        //    border: Border.all(
                        //  width: 2,
                        //)),
                        child: Text(
                          "startTime",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[200],
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                        )),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                    ),
                    Container(
                        // make the right container green
                        color: Colors.green[600],
                        //decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        //    border: Border.all(
                        //  width: 2,
                        //)),
                        child: Text(
                          "endTime",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[200],
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                        ))
                  ],
                ),
                //),
              ]),
            ),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: The blue and green containers need to reach down to the bottom of the parent.

Comment: means bottom of the screen?

Comment: Bottom of the outer column

Comment: I have added an image to what I need it to look like.

Comment: I added a height: 300, which is less then full screen and I get the message: 'A RenderFlex overflowed by 300 pixels on the bottom.

Comment: @Nefarious I tried `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.894,` this exact value which almost does the job. Its the `height` of the `Container` having blue and green background specifically try it. See if it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

I added height (300) to green and blue containers. and it works fine.[image]

**code:**

```
Column(children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          // make the full container the amber color
          color: Colors.amber[600],
          child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, children: [
            Row(children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  'windowName',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[200],
                      fontSize: 24,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.delete_outline, size: 32)),
            ]),
            //IntrinsicHeight(
            //  child:
            Row(
              //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                      height: 300,
                      // make the left container blue
                      color: Colors.blue[600],
                      //constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
                      //decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      //    border: Border.all(
                      //  width: 2,
                      //)),
                      child: Text(
                        'startTime',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[200],
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                      )),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                      height: 300,
                      // make the right container green
                      color: Colors.green[600],
                      //decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      //    border: Border.all(
                      //  width: 2,
                      //)),
                      child: Text(
                        'endTime',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[200],
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                      )),
                )
              ],
            ),
            //),
          ]),
        ),
      )
    ])
```